# Raspberry pi shutdown and power back on with UPS

Tags: pi-2, power, ups

So I have an UPS, but I want to be able to shutdown the pi and power it back on (by pressing a button or so). But I don't know how I can do this...

The UPS I'm using is te Geekworm UPS: 
[image]

Someone that can help me with this.

Kindest regards,

Robin

Comment: 10 minutes of Googling has turned up exactly 0 manufacturer's pages, documentation or spec sheets. This appears to be a grey market item with no support. I think, if you can't provide any references for the board, you're unlikely to get workable answers. Do you have anything useful you could add to your question?

Comment: http://www.raspberrypiwiki.com/index.php/Raspi_UPS_HAT_Board This is the wiki?

Comment: That's some pretty dreadful documentation! I can't find anything useful in there - the attached python example is only for displaying battery information.

Comment: As far as I know is it an UPS like another? I just need a system to cutoff the power of the battery and then reconnect the power to the pi so it can reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an on/off switch on the board, same end as the battery connector.  It's small and rectangular between an LED and an indentation on the PCB.

Comment: Seen that. I've placed a pushbutton parrallel over that button to extend it out of the case. It works fine. I'll approve your answer.